# Laravel 5.2- How to add prefix to existing url() helper function?

Tags: laravel, url, localization, laravel-5

I use localization functionality in my web application. But I want to add `App::getLocale()` to `url()`. So for example, in my view when I add `<a href="{{url('/admin')}}">link</a>` I want to display the URL in HTML as `http://localhost/mysite/en/admin`. How can I do it?

Can I customize built-in `URL` helper function?

Comment: I have the same problem right now, can you please tell me how you have solved this?

Comment: @Tim , I found solution. Check my answer.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

[image]I found solution. Tested it in laravel 5.3. It worked! Could be useful for others. 
So it is worth share:

Enter `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php` and modify code like that:

Just add `your prefix` before `$path` variable

Comment: Never edit a class in vendor folder. This folder is entirely managed by composer. Any modification in it will be erased when you will run `composer update`.

Comment: Alexandre is right, **don't do that**. Never edit anything inside of the vendor folder. As you can see from the screenshot, the function `url()` is defined only if it's not defined already. You could define your custom `url()` function inside of an helper file located in your project folder and then put it in the `autoload` section of your `composer.lock`.

Comment: Never ever do that. It will break the synchronization with production and your development code.

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 5.4, use the following

```
{{ url('Your_Prefix', 'login') }}
```

url just formats the whole path to the requested  address, you can add whatever you want in it.

Answer (score 1):

**url()** method doesn't allow that, as it generates URL for the exact value that you provide as first argument. However it's possible to achieve what you need if you switched to **route()** method and defined a prefix for your routes.

```
// define a route group with a prefix in routes.php
Route::group(['prefix' => App::getLocale()], function() {
  Route::get('admin', ['as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'AdminController@action']);
});

// generate prefixed URL
echo route('admin');
```

If your locale is **en**, then the above line should give you a URL like **/en/admin**

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I ran into the same problem today. Based on the other answers, I came up with the following solution: I created a helper class which uses the Laravel `url()` helper function, but pre-processes the `$path` variable prior to calling the helper function. I created my own implementation for both `url()` and `secure_url()` helper functions.

This was a post action after I implemented localization in my application, for which I consulted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265880/laravel-change-locale-not-working).

Take a look at my solution. I hope it is useful for someone someday:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Helpers;

class Helpers {

    /**
     * Generate a url for the application.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @param  mixed   $parameters
     * @param  bool    $secure
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\UrlGenerator|string
     */
    public static function url($path = null, $parameters = [], $secure = null) {
        $path = (string) $path;
        if (strlen($path) > 0 && $path[0] !== '/') {
            $path = '/' . $path;
        }
        return url(app()->getLocale() . $path, $parameters, $secure);
    }

    /**
     * Generate a HTTPS url for the application.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @param  mixed   $parameters
     * @return string
     */
    public static function secure_url($path, $parameters = []) {
        return static::url($path, $parameters, true);
    }

}
```