# Laravael - Language switcher not working

Tags: laravel, controller, middleware

I am trying to dynamically display the texts in two languages - English or German. But I am failing the task because nothing happens.

I have done the following:

Middleware:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    if (!\Session::has('locale')) {
        \Session::put('locale', \Config::get('app.locale'));
    }

    app()->setLocale(\Session::get('locale'));

    return $next($request);
 }

 }
```

Controller:

```
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Session;
use App;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class LanguageController extends Controller {

protected $langs = ['en', 'de'];

public function changeLanguage($lang) {
    if (in_array($lang, $this->langs)) {
        App::setLocale($lang);
        Session::put('locale', $lang);
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
}
```

Kernel:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\LanguageMiddleware::class,
];
```

View:

```
  <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">{{trans('translations.lang')}}</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
        @if(Session::get('locale')=='en')
            <a href="lang/de">Deutsch</a>
        @else
             <a href="lang/en">English</a>
        @endif
        </div>
</div>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('lang/{id}', 'LanguageController@changeLanguage');
```

Using Laravel 5.4

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check to see what is being rendered using the browser developer tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define and middleware like this :

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

/**
 * Class LocaleMiddleware.
 */
class LocaleMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure                 $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
protected $languages = ['en','de'];

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!session()->has('locale'))
    {
        session()->put('locale', $request->getPreferredLanguage($this->languages));
    }

    app()->setLocale(session('locale'));

    return $next($request);
    }
}
```

on your controller create method for change

```
public function changeLanguage($languague)
{
    if(Session::has(locale)){
        session()->set('locale', $language);}
    else{
        session()->set('locale', 'en');
    }

    return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Route look like

```
Route::get('lang/{languague}', 'LanguageController@changeLanguage');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing happens again :/

Comment: I think the problem comes from session()->set('locale', $language);
I get the following error:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::set()

But if I use session(['locale', $language]); I don''t get the error..

Comment: Apologize on laravel 5.4 the set method doesn't exist for sessions. you describe the rigth method. i will correct my answer

Comment: So when using {{trans('translations.username')}} in the view, I get translations.username and not the string I have put for a translation. Also the language doesn't change. Mean the if in the view doesn't update

Comment: Basically it's not working for German. Takes only the default en

Comment: curious add var_dump or \Log on your controller's function.

Comment: How exactly should I do this?

Comment: public function changeLanguage($languague)
{  var_dump($languague);
    if(Session::has(locale)){

      var_dump('language change to '.$language);
        session()->set('locale', $language);
       die;
  }
    else{
        session()->set('locale', 'en');
    }

    return redirect()->back();
    }

Comment: the print value contains in $languague. if german language il well define be sure your lang resource filenames are well define.

Comment: I got the following after selecting german: string(2) "de" string(21) "language change to de". The files are like lang/de/translations.php. When I change the locale in congif.app to de the page is translated, otherwise not

Comment: `app()->setLocale(session('locale')); ` don't work for you.  this link can help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265880/laravel-change-locale-not-working)

Comment: Found this article https://mydnic.be/post/laravel-5-and-his-fcking-non-persistent-app-setlocale in the link you provided. Works fine now. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score -1):

in your route command you send $id but in your controller's function you have enter $lang  and not $id. the error can come for that.

you must have this

`public function changeLanguage($id) {`

Comment: No, I don't get any