# Get Language from construct in laravel

Tags: laravel, middleware, multilingual, construct

i'm trying to get selected language in my construct to use in any function in that class:

my route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin',  'middleware' => ['AdminMiddleWare','auth','localization']], function(){
     Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.index');
});
```

My Middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Session::has('locale') AND array_key_exists(Session::get('locale'), Config::get('languages'))) {
        App::setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
    }
    else {
        App::setLocale(Config::get('app.locale'));
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

My controller :

```
public  $lang;

public function __construct()
{        
    $this->lang = Language::where('lang','=',app()->getLocale())->first();
}

public function index()
{
    $lang = $this->lang;        
    return $lang;
}
```

but i'm getting only the default locale;

but if i change the controller to this:

```
public function index()
{
    $lang = Language::where('lang','=',app()->getLocale())->first();

    return $lang;
}
```

it will work...

how to get in construct and use it in all functions??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55353631/laravel-5-8-setlocale-globally/55353834#55353834

Comment: that's what i'm doing..but the function in my controller don'y get the object from $this->lang... and i had to put      Language::where('lang','=',app()->getLocale())->first();

Comment: For me works: public function __construct() { App::setLocale(request()->lang); } Then in code App:getLocale()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel, a controller is instantiated *before* middleware has run. Your controller's constructor is making the query before the middleware has had a chance to check and store the locale value.

There are multiple ways you can set up to work around this - the important thing is to make the call *after* middleware runs. One way is to use a getter method on your controller:

```php
class Controller
{
    /**
     * @var Language
     */
    private $lang;

    public function index()
    {
        $lang = $this->getLang();

        // ...
    }

    private function getLang()
    {
        if ($this->lang) {
            return $this->lang;
        }

        return $this->lang = Language::where('lang','=',app()->getLocale())->first();
    }
}
```