# How to translate german into english using Laravel (Localization?)

Tags: php, laravel, translation, multilingual

I have a german site and want it to translate it into english with Laravel (Localization?).
There will be different links for each language, so it is not necessary to get their locale.

I've read through the docs and many articles but still am not sure how to do this.

What I need:

- I have only two languages, german(main) and english(second)
- I need the parameters `en` and `de` in the url, but I haven't found a tutorial doing this
- I think I have to use translation Strings as keys since it makes the most sense with only two languages, therefore I need a json file

So my questions:

1. I want to translate into english, but there is already an `en`-folder in the `lang`-folder, so what am I supposed to do? Just put the `en.json`-file in there?
2. Is it necessary to use middleware? Or is there another, idiot-safe way to achieve this for someone with a really small amount of experience?
3. How can I set and get the language-parameter in the url and translate the site based on it?
4. Do I only need one `en`-file to translate even though I have about 3 different routes/sites?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55353631/laravel-5-8-setlocale-globally/55353834#55353834

Comment: Laravel doesn't translate for you. You have to translate and store it then use Localization to decide when to display which language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already the structure/functionality of the Localization which is in Laravel super easy:

In folder

```
resources/lang
```

you need to have a per lang folder like

```
resources/lang/en -> English
resources/lang/de -> German/Deutsch
```

in each lang forlder you create a blade for example the app translation:

```
app.blade.php
```

you will have the following structure:

```
resources/lang/en/app.blade.php -> English
resources/lang/de/app.blade.php -> German/Deutsch
```

Where you put for example

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Language Lines
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The following language lines are used by the app library to build
    | the simple pagination links. You are free to change them to anything
    | you want to customize your views to better match your application.
    |
    */

    'greets' => 'Welcome',
];
```

in the German app.blade.php you put:

```
<?php

    return [

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Application Language Lines
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | The following language lines are used by the app library to build
        | the simple pagination links. You are free to change them to anything
        | you want to customize your views to better match your application.
        |
        */

        'greets' => 'Wilkommen',
    ];
```

Then you can call this in you blade with

```
@lang('app.greets')
```

The default language is set in `config/app.php` the locale constant where you can create the logic to switch it using for example `App::setLocale('de');`   see the used locale is just using the `App::getLocale();`

Comment: So you say I have to write a function in `config/app.php` in which I get the parameter from the url and switch the locale with `App::setLocale('en')` when `en` is the parameter for e.g?

Comment: No you cannot write a function in the config/app.php :)  This must be happen in route and controller..

Comment: This answer didn't cover my whole problem but helped me getting the solution, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I show you a method i used to translate a website in several languages with your needs in LARAVEL 5.8

In this example, my routes are translated (conforming the SEO) clicking on a flag and the text is translated in the same time.

You can use both the two methods, one for short strings and one for the long strings (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/localization#defining-translation-strings).
First you get these folders:

```
resources/lang
```

**1) For the short strings** using short keys:

```
resources/lang/de/messages.php
resources/lang/en/messages.php
```

You get php files messages, for example one of them to english:

```
<?php
// resources/lang/en/messages.php

return [

    'Willkommen' => 'Welcome',
    'kontakt' => 'contact',
    'Aktuelles' => 'News',
];
```

**2) For the long strings** using translation strings as keys:

```
resources/lang/de.json
resources/lang/en.json
```

You get json files for example one of them, german to english (en.json):

```
{
    "Ich akzeptiere die Bedingungen der Datenschutzerklärung.": "I accept the terms and conditions of the privacy policy.",
    "Das Album wurde gut aufgenommen.": "The album has been saved",
}
```

**3) Into you different blade views** files you can use both methods:

```
echo __('messages.Willkommen');
echo __('Ich akzeptiere die Bedingungen der Datenschutzerklärung.');

or with the blade helpers:

{{ __('messages.Willkommen') }}
@lang('messages.Willkommen'')
```

**4) For the route you can translate the url** conforming to the SEO for exemple:

```
https://website.com/de/aktuelles/
https://website.com/en/news/
```

You have to create two files for the route:

```
resources/lang/de/routes.php
resources/lang/en/routes.php
```

You get files routes, for example one of them to english:

```
<?php
// resources/lang/en/routes.php

return [

    'willkommen' => 'welcome',
    'aktuelles' => 'news',
];
```

**5) Switching route with flags,** you have to use config/app.php with the parameters:

```
<?php
// config/app.php

'locales' => ['de', 'en'],
'fallback_locale' => 'de',
```

and to get a language switcher, you have to add this code into the layout blade for example:

```
@foreach(config('app.locales') as $locale)
    @if($locale != session('locale'))
        <a class="btn btn-sm" href="{{ route('language', $locale) }}">
            <img alt="{{ $locale }}" title="{{ $locale }}"
        src="{!! asset('images/flags/' . $locale . '.png') !!}"/>
        </a>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

**6) Adding a route for the switching flag action 'language'.**

Naming other routes in routes/web.php:

> 'locale.name'

keeping the name always in german (your main language).

You get german name and english name:

> 'de.aktuelles'
>
> 'en.aktuelles'

```
<?php
// routes/web.php

Route::name('language')->get('/{lang}', 'YourController@language');

foreach(['de', 'en'] as $locale) {
    Route::prefix($locale)->group(function() use ($locale) {
        Route::get(trans('routes.aktuelles', array(), $locale), function() {
            return view('aktuelles', ['name'=>'aktuelles', 'localName' => trans('routes.aktuelles', array(), session('locale'))]);//trans('routes.aktuelles');
        })->name($locale.'.'.'aktuelles');
    });
}
```

You can add a default route for the main page of your site as following:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/de/willkommen');
});
```

**7) Now you have to add a middleware** which verify if a locale is registed in session:

```
<?php
app/Http/Middleware/Locale.php

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!session ()->has ('locale')) {
        session (['locale' => $request->getPreferredLanguage (config ('app.locales'))]);
    }
    $locale = session ('locale');
    app ()->setLocale ($locale);
    setlocale (LC_TIME, app()->environment('local') ? $locale : config('locale.languages')[$locale][1]);
    
    return $next ($request);
}
```

You add this middleware class in the app/Http/Kernel.php:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Locale::class,
    ],
    ...
];
```

**8) You also need a controller for the 'language' action** (switching language):

To do that i need to get the previous route name for adding the new locale to redirect to the right route.
I use an excellent tip [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690202/previous-route-name-in-laravel-5-1-5-8) to do that!

```
<?php
// app/Http/Controllers/YourController.php

public function language(String $locale, Request $request)
{
    // Previous route name Visit 
    $oneRoute = app('router')->getRoutes()->match(app('request')->create(url()->previous()))->getName();
    // Replacing the locale in the road name
    $nextRoute = substr_replace($oneRoute, $locale, 0, 2);

    $locale = in_array ($locale, config ('app.locales')) ? $locale : config ('app.fallback_locale');
    session (['locale' => $locale]);

    return redirect()->route($nextRoute);
}
```

**9) Perhaps you would like to translate menu items** in addition to the routes. So in your blade view:

```
{{-- ie for one item --}}
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route(session('locale') .'.aktuelles') }}">{{ __('messages.Aktuelles') }}</a>
</li>
```

**10) At the end** i haven't solved the fact that you would like to remove the particle "de" from your German URLs, by example:

> yourwebsite.com/aktuelles

instead of

> yourwebsite.com/de/aktuelles

...